# How to run a Service using cmd script in Windows XP?

Tags: services, batch

How can I run a service which has status "stopped" using a `cmd` script?

Comment: you've asked 78 questions before, and I'm pretty sure almost all of them have been edited if not for grammar fixes, to remove the  signatures. Please don't use them - [faq#signatures].  Please review the previous edits

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sc`.

```
sc query
```

Lists all running services installed on your computer.

```
sc query > c:\services.txt
```

Dumps the list of all running services into a file named *services.txt* in C:.

```
sc query state= inactive
```

Lists all stopped services installed on your computer.

```
sc query state= inactive > c:\dis_services.txt
```

Dumps the list of all stopped services into a file named *dis_services.txt* in C:.

```
sc start [service_name]
```

Starts a service called [service_name], for example:

```
sc start Spooler
```

Starts the Print Spooler service.

```
sc stop [service_name]
```

Stops a service called [service_name], for example:

```
sc stop Spooler
```

Stops the Print Spooler service.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Powershell then you can use the following commands:

```
get-service
start-service
stop-service
```

sc doesn't work in powershell straight away as it's aliased to a command called set-content.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Larssend** answer view this answer with **SC** description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/133926/1776789.
For me it's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample batch (*.BAT) file I use to start my local SQL Server instances (running as Windows services):

```
@Echo Off
NET START MSSQLSERVER
NET START MSSQL$SECONDARY
NET START MSSQL$CMS
```

Similarly, the following stops them all, one by one:

```
@Echo Off
NET STOP MSSQLSERVER
NET STOP MSSQL$SECONDARY
NET STOP MSSQL$CMS
```

So, use the **NET START|STOP ServiceName** command.